# Aspect based sentiment analysis in python

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I am fascinated by the book "Sentiment Analysis and Opinion Mining" by [Liu Bing](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/SentimentAnalysis-and-OpinionMining.pdf) and I have implemented a small programm that gets aspects of text.

I searched my texts for a list of positive and negative words by [Hu](http://www.idiap.ch/~apbelis/hlt-course/positive-words.txt) and found the nearest nouns or personal pronoun next to the sentiment words with  nltk.tokenizer . The results are quite interesting but I am struggling to detect negations and context.

Example from Amazon:

> "I love spicy ramen, but for whatever reasons this thing burns my stomach badly and the burning sensation doesn't go away for like 3 hours! Not sure if that is healthy or not .... and you can buy this at Walmart for $0.28, way cheaper than Amazon."

My program returns a list of tuples ("sentiment word", "aspect", "sentiment"). 1 indicates positive sentiment and 0 negative sentiment.

```
[(u'love', u'i', 1),
(u'love', u'spicy', 1),
(u'burns', u'thing', 0),
(u'badly', u'stomach', 0),
(u'burning', u'stomach', 0),
(u'sensation', u'stomach', 1),
(u'healthy', u'healthy', 1),
(u'cheaper', u'way', 1)]
```

It seems that the method can capture some aspects but is far from being correct. Furthermore, I am really far from Liu's examples (page 23):

> I bought a Samsung camera and my friends brought a Canon camera
>   yesterday. (2) In the past week, we both used the cameras a lot. (3)
>   The photos from my Samy are not that great, and the battery life is
>   short too. (4) My friend was very happy with his camera and loves its
>   picture quality. (5) I want a camera that can take good photos. (6) I
>   am going to return it tomorrow

I really would like to improve so that I can capture the aspects and sentiment correctly. I know this is quite a general question but could you recommend packages and reading to me?

Best and many thanks
Alex

Comment: Check about dependency parsing.

Comment: Your ramen example is way more complex than the six examples you give.  And your results seem good: if you show me those word pairs and ask me (with no other context) to say if it is positive or negative, I think I agree with all of them (well, "sensation stomach" is neutral).

Having said that, this question will be closed unless you can find a way to rephrase it so that you can objectively mark one of the (potential) answers as correct. (That is why general questions, asking for reading material suggestions are discouraged on StackOverflow.)